# How do i prevent div from changing width when going from nothing to position:fixed?

Tags: jquery, css, position, fixed, sidebar

I have used this code: http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/

to make my sidebar sticky.

However as soon as the top of the browser hits the top of the sidebar and the position of it becomes fixed, the width of the  sidebar changes.

Here is my CSS for its containers as well as the sidebar:

```
#content-wrap {
height:auto;
min-height:100%;
width:80%;
background:#fff;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}

#content {
min-height:100%;
padding-top:5%;
padding-bottom:5%;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:auto;
}

.sidebar {
width:25%;
background: #333;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
height:250px;
color:white;
overflow:visible;
max-width:277px;
}
```

Can anybody tell me how i can work around this?

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKendle/GdLw8/1/

**NOTE:** Width HAS to be in %.

Comment: Can you set up an example in jsfiddle.net?  Also include your HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to stay the same width, you could put another div around your sidebar div that is set to 25% width (basically, the same style as `.sidebar`).  That would remain when the sidebar becomes `fixed` and hold that space until it returns to `relative` positioning when it gets "dropped off".

Comment: Good idea. I just tried it though, and it did not work.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, you needed to select jQuery in the left hand drop down menu.  I also made the content holding div 2000px tall to force a scrollbar so you can test properly.

I can look more into this later, but first of all, you have the content div at 80%.  Once that sidebar gets `fixed` to the window, it goes to 25% of 100% (document width) rather than 25% of 80% (content div).  http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKendle/GdLw8/1/

Comment: Ah okay, i'm farily new to jsfiddle. This gave me a better understanding of the problem, so thank you for that.

And from what you say, a new div around the sidebar wont help, as it will still be 25% compared to full document width, and not 25% of 80%.

Comment: If you're dead set on keeping it a percentage width, even once it's in `fixed` position, you could, at the same time you assign it fixed positioning, change the percent to match the new percent of the page width.  So, if it's 25% of 80%, do the math:  25% of 80% = 20% of 100%.  Right?  Still not sure that's how you're going to want to approach this, though.  If you could set the width once it affixes itself to the top, you could set the CSS width to the `outerWidth()` of the thing, at the last second.

Comment: One more thing, I add `*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }` at the top of *all* of my Stylesheets.  This makes it so that padding isn't *added* to the outside of widths, but rather is pushed *inside* of divs.  That way you can have padding, and still have your widths add up to 100%.  Not sure if you've seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned before you can wrap an element around the fixed positioned element with the same dimensions.

```
var div = $('<div>', {
    width : $('#sourceElm').width(),
});

$('#sourceElm').wrap(div);
```